# An argument for 'renderer' was not provided

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This is my directive:

```
export class HighlightDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'highlight');
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'highlight');
    }

}
```

And this is the corresponding spec.ts:

```
describe('HighlightDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {

    let ElementRefMock = {
      nativeElement: document.createElement('div')
    };

    let Renderer2Mock = {
      //CODE
    };

    const directive = new HighlightDirective(ElementRefMock, Renderer2Mock );
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Please help me to mock the Renderer2 dependency inside spec.ts

Comment: Don't mock it. Use an actual test with Angular support, which tests a component with a template using your directive, triggers your mouse events, and checks that the CSS class is added/removed. https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-dom-testing

Comment: You can't unit test directives directly. You have to create a temporary component inside the test file, assign the directive and then test then that component. You'll have to dispatch mouse events manually.